# Google Managed VM Instance group does not get latest image when created/replaced

Tags: python, docker, google-cloud-platform, cloudbuild.yaml

I have a cloud build trigger for a branch to build a docker image and to replace vm instances from a group with latest image, I know that before some time when we did a push to github, it replaced vm instances with new ones and the code was updated inside the containers, but it is not happening anymore. It always it is a one update behind, so for a change we need to run the trigger again to update.

```
[steps:
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
  args: [ build, -t, gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$_APP_NAME, . ]
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
  args: [ compute, instance-groups, managed, rolling-action, replace, $_INSTANCE_GROUP_NAME, --region=$_INSTANCE_GROUP_REGION , --max-unavailable=0, --max-surge=3]

images:
- gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$_APP_NAME]
```

I tried to put a "sleep 60" between the steps and also wrote a script to remove images, but still the same result.

Answer (score 1):

For all that have a similar problem:
The idea is that the image was tagged and build but it was uploaded and pushed to registry after the all the steps, so the vm instances were using the outdated image.
To solve this you need to add a step to push image to the registry
Something like this:

```
step 1...
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
  args: [ push, gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$_APP_NAME]
step 3...
```